# Ubuntu 16.04 login screen inactive

Tags: drivers, apt, graphics, lock-screen

Good Afternoon,
I am using Dell Inspiron 5110 with Ubuntu 16.04.

After update several days ago, my display started to dim. I looked many opinions on the matter and i came to the conclusion, that there is a problem with my video drivers. So i followed the instructions to edit my xorg.conf to

Section "Device"
Identifier "Card0"
Driver "intel"
Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
EndSection

I am not sure that this is the problem or it is more general, but after restart it is impossible for me to log in. I see only the login screen and my keyboard and mouse are inactive.

I restarted the laptop and open recovery mode. Try to "sudo apt-get update" from the console (hoping to reinstall the video drivers and fix this, also tried different scripts from the forums), but i have error msg: "Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old one". So i read that need to check my "/etc/apt/sources.list". Which i did open with "nano /etc/apt/sources.list". Some links inside had "gr." prefix. After more digging for info, i executed script to remove the prefix. But error msg is the same.

So far i do not have any progress. Generally i can reinstall the system, but need to save my files.  I am new to Linux OS, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your goal is to save your files.
One possible solution is to install Ubuntu on new partition (keeping your current installation and files on different.) This will allow you to access your files and copy to exernal USB/HDD, if the data is not to big or you have enough free space on external HDD. 
After this step reinstall, "the broken partition", in case you didn't found how to fix it.